# Getting properties on a drop down hover menu working correctly using CSS and HTML5

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu, hover, submenu

So I'm pretty new to CSS and HTML and I'm trying to get this drop down hover menu to work right.

[Here's a link to the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6xLqU/16)

Under Link 3, there's a sub-menu with links that appear under it. I want it so that when the user hovers over one of the sublinks, the parent link's (Link 3) background color remains highlighted rather than fading away back to blue. This is the CSS I'm using to highlight each link during a hover.

```
 #menu a:hover, #menu .current_page_item a 
    {
        text-decoration: none;
        background:#d4728b;
    }
```

This code also makes it so that the current link that is hovered over will be highlighted, but I would like it so that when the cursor is hovering over another link in the menu, the current_page highlight will shift to that link rather than two links being highlighted at one time. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set your `li` to change color opposed to the anchor.

```
#menu li:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background:#d4728b;
}
```

rough fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6xLqU/19/

Comment: Is there a way so that the highlight can only be applied to one menu link? The current_page_item class highlights whatever the link is currently on, but is there a way so that when I hover over Link 2, the highlight from Link 1 will disappear?

Comment: only way I really know is to use some jQuery. else use a slightly different color to indicate current_page: http://jsfiddle.net/6xLqU/24/

Comment: That's probably the easiest solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. please select an answer to your question and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

you could add the hover selector to the list rather than the anchor. This works because the sub-menu is a child of the li but not the anchor.

```
#menu li:hover a{
    background:#d4728b;
}
```